# Create a custom installer to replicate a linux installation

Tags: live-usb

I've been building an ubuntu 20.04 install on an older system, getting it's hardware to run by tracking down the needed drivers and installing packages to accommodate it's more limited hardware resources.

Now, I want to duplicate that install across multiple machines of the same vintage.  It's easily done with dd and a copy of the master disk image, but I need one more thing to complete the process - a way to perform a fresh install of this specific installation from removable media.  USB preferably, though CD / DVD is not out of the question.

The issue, of course, is how to get this done.  I know there's ways to create live versions of existing installs (like linux-live, among others), but I doubt that's of any use over a standard linux live install.

I'm considering the case where one of these machines has a dead HDD and it's in the hands of a user who lacks the desire / ability to manage imaging the disk externally.  The goal would be to install the new HDD in the machine and then boot the machine from USB or CD/DVD and have the live distro just write the master image to the new disk with little or no interaction required from the user.

I imagine a custom version of Slax might get that done.  I could combine it with a copy of the image and a simple script that gets executed on startup which runs something like, 'dd if=/usb/linux/master.img of=/dev/sda1'

Still, I'm wondering if there's a better, more manageable way of doing that.  It feels a bit.. hacky?  Or perhaps there's a linux distro / framework that's better suited for what I have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily want a custom installer, but a backup software that can do *bare metal recovery*.

Typically, such backup software can create disk image backups in bootable format. When booting from the backup media, it typically offers a simplified user interface that allows you to identify the version of the backup, choose the disk/partition to restore it to, and partition disks either automatically to match the original, or manually.

Usually you can also prepare a backup media for fully automated restoration of the dead simple "insert media; boot system from media; press Y to confirm" variety, if you make that choice when creating the backup.

For open-source solutions, at least [Relax-and-Recover (ReaR)](https://www.tecmint.com/rear-backup-and-recover-a-linux-system/) or [Bacula](https://www.bacula.org/) might fit the bill. ReaR might even be present in Debian/Ubuntu package repositories. I'm sure there are other options too.